# Delay privilege separation in openSSH

Tags: linux, openssh, privileges

This question is about delaying the privilege separation in openSSH.

This is what I have learned from: [Privilege Separated OpenSSH](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep.html)

Monitor process spawns unprivileged process for network processing (key exchange and authentication) and if user is authenticated, monitor spawns ***user privilege*** process after which pty will be allocated and user specific shell is spawned.

In my case, I need to spawn a shell (custom script) which first enters into a particular namespace and then call the script to spawn the shell. Since at this stage, user privilege process is spawning custom script, it is not able to enter into a particular namespace.

What I have seen from code that following lines of code in dropping the privilege (in privsep_postauth) to user.

```
-
668     -
669     /* Demote the private keys to public keys. */   -
670     demote_sensitive_data();    -
671     -
672     reseed_prngs(); -
673     -
674     /* Drop privileges */   -
675     do_setusercontext(authctxt->pw);
```

Can you guys guide me whether is it safe to do so and also how we can delay this privilege separation until shell is spawned. ?

Comment: Could you add your shell script or a dummy script that produce same issue?

Comment: Thanks @Biswapriyo for replying back. I removed "do_setusercontext" untill shell is spawned and set the usercontext after that and now able to enter into  namespace.
I just want to see what security impact it could be possible since now tty is also allocated with root privilege.